# Changing Activity After receiving push notification on Background

Tags: java, android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push

Suppose I am in Activity A.

What I have done so far is, After I receive push notification, if the app is in foreground it shows an alert dialog and allows user to tap and go to next activity B.

And if the app is in background, a notification is shown and when tapped it goes to activity B. It is alright till this point.

But what if user chooses to open the app via its launcher. It will still be in Activity A.

I am unable to change its root activity to Activity B while the app is in background. (It was pretty easy in Swift as i only had to change its `rootviewcontroller`) It is super important to change its root activity after i receive the push notification

Answer (score 1):

Since Android defines it's root activity as a Launcher inside the manifest file I don't think it is possible to change the activity from where the app launches when the user opens it from the launcher. One thing you can try is to detect whether the notification is received or not on start of Activity A and then move to Activity B if the notification is received.

Comment: Thank you for ur suggestion... But i guess there has to be something that can change update the root activity from the launcher as well

Answer (score 1):

As @Shaishav told you can't change the launcher activity on run time but what you can do is implement a splash screen, and check in the activity if you found any notification true navigate to user to activity B, else in activity A.